# Lower Semi-Continuity and Joint Measurability

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

The following is from "Infinite Dimensional Analysis" by Aliprantis & Border where the Carathéodory function $f$ is measurable in its first argument and continuous in its second argument:
[image: analysis]

Does the same result hold if $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is merely lower-semicontinuous in its second argument?
The logic from the proof doesn't hold up because it is not guaranteed that $f(s, x_m)\to f(s,x)$, but is there a way to make this hold anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true if continuity is replaced by lower semicontinuity: Take $S=X=[0,1]$, $Y=\mathbb R$. Let $B\subset [0,1]$ be not measurable.
Define
$$
f(s,x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } s=x \text{ and } x\not\in B\\
1 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
For fixed $s$, $x\mapsto f(x,s)$ is lower semicontinuous, and for fixed $x$, $s\mapsto f(x,s)$ is measurable.

However, $f(s,s) = \chi_B$, which is not measurable, and $f$ cannot be jointly measurable. Also note that
$$
f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \bigcup_{x\in X} \{x\} \times (B\setminus\{x\}).
$$

The claim is true, if $f$ is the pointwise limit of Caratheodory functions. Such measurability issues are discussed in the book 'Nonlinear superposition operators' by Appell and Zabrejko.